# Express app.use under if statement

Tags: node.js, express

I don't know if this already being ask since I can't really grasp how express app.use works. To clarify my problem I have a situation where I want to use different routes under certain circumstance but declaring app.use under if statement or node.env will always return 404. I even use module with `require('./router')(app)`, but the problem won't go away. Any solution for this, or if it already being ask it'll be helpful to point out the solution links, thanks in advance.

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var prod_routes = require('./routes_prod');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
if ('production' == env) {
    app.use('/', prod_routes);
} else {
    app.use('/', routes);
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing the `var env` prior to `if else` statement

Comment: Does it work without the `if`? Your code here looks fine to me. Would you mind sharing the contents of `routes.js`?

Comment: yes, I already do that, printing console.log will give the output, which mean the code block is running, but without the node_env or simply passing a boolean as arg will 404 still

Comment: @kraf it works without the if

Comment: maybe out of the question's scope but would be nice to move `require` to the conditions as well. No reason to require 2 modules when you are going to use only one

Comment: can you please add the error log

Comment: @smnbbrv i moved it to require, still 404

Comment: @syarul it should not solve the problem, just the code will be more logical

Comment: Did you try both of them without the `if`? My guess would be, that only one of them is not working and it's just a small typo inside either `routes` or `routes_prod`.

Comment: @kraf without if works, no typo. Maybe I need to remove wrap function around routes

Comment: You are either always testing `app.use('/', prod_routes);` without the `if` or  `app.use('/', routes);`. You should try the other one. I'm pretty sure it will give you a 404 without the `if`.

Comment: It seems I'm working behind asynchronous method, the ```routes``` map to 404 since routes haven't finish yet. Though I'm not sure how make ```app.use``` wait